# Can not run functions in vue.js. X is not a function at Vue$3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, datetime-format, flatpickr

I have a date picker which returns me data in a datatime format. I need to pass this data to my api which accepts the data in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

I have:

```
  methods: {
onDateChanged: function(event) {
    console.log(event.startDate)
    console.log(event.endDate)
    this.startDate = event.startDate.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"-");
    this.endDate = event.endDate.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"-");
    this.loadTopBar();
    console.log(this.startDate.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"-"))
    console.log(this.endDate.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"-"))
},

loadTopBar: function(){
  var vm = this
  axios.get('/api/v2/metrics/', {
      params: {
          start: this.startDate,
          end: this.endDate
      }
  })
 .then(function(response) {
    vm.json = response.data
    // Sessions
```

The first two console logs correctly output in the console `Tue May 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)` and `Tue May 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)`

The `.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"-"))` also works on a simple js file, I also tried in a function:

```
`function formatDate(date) {
    return `${ date.getFullYear() }-${ ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) }-${ ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) }`;
}
```

which also works fine in a simple js file. However when using either within vue.js I get these errors:

```
app.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: this.startDate.toISOString is not a function
at Vue$3.onDateChanged (app.js:27)
at EventEmitter.boundFn (vue@2.3.2:167)
at EventEmitter.emit (emitter.js:59)
at Flatpickr.onClose (datepicker.js:42)
at triggerEvent (flatpickr@2.6.1:1551)
at Flatpickr.close (flatpickr@2.6.1:834)
at selectDate (flatpickr@2.6.1:1310)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (flatpickr@2.6.1:204)
```

But even though I have these error axios calls the correct data, so the parameters are actually passed in the correct format. Why does this happen?
How can I get rid of these errors?

The datepicker library is [flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/)

P.s. I'm not sure if it's related but I'm using [this event emitter](https://gist.github.com/mudge/5830382) to transfer the startDate and endDate variables between my eventpicker vue.js app and all the other vue.js apps which load the charts etc.

Comment: Isn't it because you're assigning `this.startDate` to a string, and then trying to call `toISOString()` on it, which only works on date objects?

Comment: Hi @EricGuan, but in that case the whole axios call would not work no? Plus the same code works fine on a simple js file, and the output really looks like a date time object, i.e. `Tue May 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)` is there a way to check if it's a datetime object?

Comment: The error Eric mentioned is in your last two `console.log` statements. They don't affect the axios call.